# DataGrid ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged event occurring continuously

Tags: c#, wpf

I have used a Datagrid and subscribed with its ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged event.
The Item source of the Datagrid is a simple datatable (GDItems). 
There is another datatable(GDAllItems) which holds the actual dataset obtained from database.

The logic is written this way :

1. While binding GDItems first time to datagrid first 50 rows are fetched from GDAllItems and shown.
2. As the user scrolls down at the bottom, scroll changed event is fired and next set of 50 rows are fetched from GDAllItems and set to GDItems so that now total of 100 rows are seen in datagrid. This continues till all the rows are fetched.

Now the main problem is ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged event is getting fired continuously and debugger doesn't come out of it.

Most of the columns in xaml are "DataGridTextColumn" except for two columns which are set as "DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate" as an editable "TextBox" is required inside it.
If these 2 columns are removed or their type is changed to  "DataGridTextColumn", then the code runs perfectly (ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged event fires only once and not continuous).

I am not able to figure out the connection between the use of "DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate" and the event occurring continuously.

Help Appreciated!

XAML Code :

```
<DataGrid Name="gridFinalResult" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
ItemsSource="{Binding GDFinalResult,IsAsync=True}" 
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemFinalResult}"                               RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"                                               CanUserSortColumns="True" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"                                                  TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" FrozenColumnCount="1"                                                  VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"                                                 SelectionMode="Single" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"                                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanUserResizeRows="True"                                                  CanUserReorderColumns="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"                                                  Width="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"                                                  Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"                                                  HeadersVisibility="Column" RowHeight="NaN"                                                  EnableColumnVirtualization="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True">

<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CompanyNo}" Header="Company&#x0a;(#)"
Width="60"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CompanyName}" Header="Company&#x0a;Name"
Width="110"/>


<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataTemplate> <TextBox properties:Tracker.Property="Text" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="54"
Name="txtNewQty" Numeric:ZeroNumericMaskBehavior.Mask="NonNegativeNumber" MaxLength="6" Text="{Binding Path=FinalRecommendedQty, StringFormat='{}{0:#,0;}', Mode=TwoWay}"
LostFocus="txtNewQty_LostFocus" TextChanged="txtNewQty_TextChanged"
GotFocus="txtNewQty_GotFocus" IsTabStop="True" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue">
</TextBox> </DataTemplate></DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Scroll Changed Code :

```
private void gridFinalResult_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var scrollViewer = VisualTreeHelpers.FindChild<ScrollViewer>(gridFinalResult);
        if (rsoVM.GDFinalResult != null && rsoVM.GDFinalDBResult != null)
            {
                if (rsoVM.GDFinalDBResult.Rows.Count.ToString() == rsoVM.GDFinalResult.Rows.Count.ToString())
                {                    
                    return;
                }
            }

            if (scrollViewer.VerticalOffset > 0 && scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight > 0)
            {
                if (scrollViewer.VerticalOffset == scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight)
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable("dt");
                    dt = rsoVM.GDFinalResult.Copy();

                    object getSelecteditem = null;

                    if (gridFinalResult.SelectedItem != null)
                        getSelecteditem = gridFinalResult.SelectedItem;

                    DataRow[] drRSOList = rsoVM.GDFinalResult.Select("RowID = MAX(RowID)");

                    if (drRSOList.Length > 0)
                    {
                        int i = 0;

                        for(Int32 j = Convert.ToInt32(drRSOList[0]["RowID"].ToString()) + 1 ; j <= Convert.ToInt32(drRSOList[0]["RowID"].ToString()) + 15; j++)
                        {
                            dt.ImportRow(rsoVM.GDFinalDBResult.Rows[j]);
                        }



                        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                        {
                            rsoVM.GDFinalResult = dt;
                            rsoVM.OnPropertyChanged("GDFinalResult");
                        }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);

                            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                            {
                            scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight / 2);

                            if (getSelecteditem != null)
                            {
                                long ID = long.Parse(((System.Data.DataRowView)(getSelecteditem)).Row.ItemArray[0].ToString());
                                int index = CommonClass.GetIndex(rsoVM.GDFinalResult, ID, "RowID");
                                if (index != -1)
                                {
                                    gridFinalResult.SelectedItem = getSelecteditem;

                                    DataGridRow dgrow = (DataGridRow)gridFinalResult.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(gridFinalResult.Items[index]);
                                    if (dgrow != null)
                                        dgrow.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
                                }
                            }
                        }),
                    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
                    }
                }
            }            
        }
```

Comment: can you put your code plz (the ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged) and the XAML of the DataGrid

Comment: @HakamFostok - please check below code

Comment: PLEASE, update your question and put the code inside it, the code in the comments is not readable at all in this way

Comment: there is an edit link below the question, you can use it to update your question and insert the code by indenting it with 4 spaces

Comment: @HakamFostok : I have uploaded the code. Will you please check the same.

Comment: How do you manage to figure this? any solution??